# Array of objects return it based on the key value and return an array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

1. I have cars array of objects and i would like to return array based
   on make value arry of objects which contains 2 value pair var cars =

   ```
   [ { make: 'audi', model: 'r8',      year: '2012' } 
   , { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' } 
   , { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion',  year: '2015' } 
   , { make: 'kia',  model: 'optima',  year: '2012' } 
   , { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5',     year: '2013' }]
   ```

Output like

```
[ { Id: 'audi-group', value: 'audi-group' } , { id: 'r8',   value:
'2012' } , { id: 'r5',   value: '2013' },   {id:'ford-group',
value:'ford-group'},   {id: 'fusion',  value: '2015' } //... ]
```

All "make" based order should come

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.reduce`

Comment: Could you help me with the code snippet, thank you